# Open Cart 3 How to get sku of cart product

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, sku

i am trying to build a extension where i want to get sku value of product on cart page, checkout page and product page. I have set the fields at backend where admin can set the company id which will be pass in button URL. how can i get the sku value on cart page. I tried many different methods but it dosent work. i am also trying to get it on product & checkout page. is there anyone who can help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Fast Checkout</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <link>https://google.com</link>
    <author>Jamil Baig</author>
    <code>fast_checkout</code>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/cart.twig">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<a href="{{ cart }}"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
            function clearCart() {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'https://adup.iot',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function(json) {
                      $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
                      if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
                          location = 'https://adup.io';
                      } else {
                          $('#cart > ul').load('https://adup.io ul li');
                      }
                  }
              });
            }
            </script>
            <a style="cursor:pointer;"><strong><i class="fa fa-times"></i> {{button_fastcheckout }}</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{{ cart }}"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function add() {]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[public function clearcart() {
                $this->load->language('checkout/cart');
                $json = array();
                $this->cart->clear();
                $total = 0;
                
                unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);
                unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
                unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
                unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
                unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
                unset($this->session->data['reward']);

                $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), $this->currency->format($total, $this->config->get('config_currency')));

                if (isset($this->request->get['shoppingcart']) && $this->request->get['shoppingcart']=='true') {
                    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
                } else {
                    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
                    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
                }
            }]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/common/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->load->language('common/cart');]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$data['button_fastcheckout'] = $this->language->get('button_fastcheckout');]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->load->language('checkout/cart');]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$this->load->controller("admin/controller/extension/module/fastcheckout");
         $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $data['button_fastcheckout'] = $this->language->get('Fast Checkout');
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
        $data['product_id'] = $product['product_id'];
        }

            $data['link_button'] = 'https://adup.io/?companyid='.$this->config->get('module_fastcheckout_company_id').'&sku='.$data['product_id'].'&p_id='.$data['product_id'];]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/language/en-gb/common/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$_['text_recurring'] = 'Payment Profile';]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[$_['button_fastcheckout']  = 'Clear Cart';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/cart.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$_['column_total']= 'Total';]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[$_['button_fastcheckout']  = 'Clear Cart';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/cart.twig">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[{% if modules %}]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[<a href="{{ link_button }}" class="btn btn-default" title="{{button_fastcheckout}}">{{button_fastcheckout}}</a>]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved

after getting product id, i can get sku of product on cart page